# SSL Verify Error Ruby

Tags: ruby, ssl

So I have this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'net/https'
require 'open-uri'

puts "HTTPS Client for Ruby!"
puts "Enter the URL"
site = gets.chomp

url = URI.parse(site)

http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host,url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER

http.cert_store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
http.cert_store.set_default_paths
http.cert_store.add_file('/home/user/sec/certs/cacert.pem')

page = Net::HTTP.get(url)

puts page
```

It works fine. It's able to grab the html of the homepage of pretty much any http or https website. However, I have an HTTPS enabled webserver set up in a virtual machine which it doesn't work with. Before I enabled SSL on the webserver this script grabbed the html just fine. So my question is, why do I receive this error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:920:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:920:in `block in connect'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:67:in `timeout'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:920:in `connect'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:583:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:478:in `get_response'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:455:in `get'
    from https_client.rb:20:in `<main>'
```

When running the script trying to grab the html of my web server? The path that I've specified has an actual certificate there.

Answer (score -1):

You get that error when the SSL certificate is self signed/not from a verified ssl provider.So assuming the website you are pulling from, is your own/you trust it and hasn't a verified certificate, change

`http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER`

to

`http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE`

[same situation](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/176626)

Comment: This is the worst advice you could ever give. Turning on certificate verification defeats thew whole purpose and should not be done.

Comment: @TanelSuurhans it would be except the OP stated that they are connecting to a HTTPS server the OP setup, and based on the error it means most likely the server they setup has a self signed certificate!

Comment: and if you can't trust your own server, who can you trust